# How do I adjust the slice_index of a cut plane in Mayavi?

Tags: python, visualization, mayavi

Using [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html), I get a nice cut plane with my data:

```
SF  = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(H)
obj = mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget(SF,
              plane_orientation='y_axes',
              slice_index=16)
```

How do I programmatically adjust the `slice_index` on the `mlab.pipeline.image_plane_widget` for animation purposes? I tried looking through `help(obj)` and it's a mess of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Mayavi "record" button, I found that you can get a sense for what is being called when then plane moves. It's not as simple as `slice_index`, which can only be used at creation, but at least it shows the right calls. A single move of the plane can be recreated with the following commands:

```
image_plane_widget1 = engine.scenes[0].children[1].children[0].children[0]
image_plane_widget1.ipw.origin = array([  0.5,  21. ,   0.5])
image_plane_widget1.ipw.point1 = array([  0.5,  21. ,  50.5])
image_plane_widget1.ipw.point2 = array([ 50.5,  21. ,   0.5])
image_plane_widget1.ipw.origin = array([  0.5,  21. ,   0.5])
image_plane_widget1.ipw.point1 = array([  0.5,  21. ,  50.5])
image_plane_widget1.ipw.point2 = array([ 50.5,  21. ,   0.5])
```